# "Unknown bind columns" error when accessing has_many associated class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I've written a rather simple app to list out some test data I've collected. Each test run has several configuration entities associated with it. When listing out test runs I have no troubles and the site performs as expected. However, when I created a model to associate the configurations I ran into an error that isn't resolving.

My code uses two classes: TestRun and TestConfiguration:

```
# test_run.rb
class TestRun < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'testrun'
    self.inheritance_column = "inheritance_type"

    has_many :testconfigurations, class_name: "TestConfiguration"   
end

#test_configuration.rb
class TestConfiguration < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'testconfiguration'
    self.inheritance_column = "inheritance_type"

    belongs_to :testrun
end
```

The models were created for an existing set of tables from a DB. I've dumped the schema from the DB in my db/schema.rb:

```
# snippets from schema.rb

  create_table "TestRun", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "label",            limit: 128
    t.string   "description",      limit: 256
    t.integer  "result_id",                    null: false
    t.string   "type",             limit: 32
    t.datetime "starttime"
    t.datetime "endtime"
    t.string   "name",             limit: 128
    t.integer  "owner_id"
    t.integer  "configuration_id",             null: false
    t.integer  "environment_id",               null: false
  end

  add_index "TestRun", ["configuration_id"], name: "IX_TestRun_configid"
  add_index "TestRun", ["result_id"], name: "IX_TestRun_resultid"
  add_index "TestRun", ["type"], name: "IX_TestRun_type"

  create_table "TestConfiguration", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "build",      limit: 128
    t.string   "branch",     limit: 24
    t.string   "label",      limit: 256
    t.datetime "date"
    t.string   "type",       limit: 64,  null: false
    t.integer  "testrun_id",             null: false
  end

  add_index "TestConfiguration", ["branch"], name: "IX_TestConfiguration_branch"
  add_index "TestConfiguration", ["build"], name: "IX_TestConfiguration_build"
  add_index "TestConfiguration", ["testrun_id"], name: "IX_TestConfiguration_testrunid"
  add_index "TestConfiguration", ["type"], name: "IX_TestConfiguration_type"
```

I've written a very basic listing of TestRun and that works just fine (confirming that rails connected to my DB and the schema works for TestRun and another class, and that all the basic plumbing is in place for simple listings). Here's the controller:

```
class TestrunController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @testruns = TestRun.last(100).reverse
  end
end
```

Lastly, I've written a view for this, and that's where the trouble happens. Here's the relevant snippet from the view where the error happens:

```
    <% @testruns.each do |run| %>
        <tr class="data_row">
          <td><%= run.id %></td>
          <td><%= run.type %></td>

          <td>
            <% run.testconfigurations.each do |config| %>
                <%= config.branch %><br>
            <% end %>
          </td>
```

The page worked until I added the 3 lines relating to iterating through the testconfigurations. Now, with those lines it barfs with an error like this:

***Unknown bind columns. We can account for this.***

The following line is the highlighted problem in the error:

```
<% run.testconfigurations.each do |config| %>
```

I've played around with the models, schema, and tried lots of trick on the view but my rails knowledge is too young and powerless to conquer this error. Any insights as to why the columns cannot bind?

Comment: Could use just `@testruns = TestRun.last(100)`

Comment: Yup, true, will probably save some bytes. Thanks.

Comment: I thought you reverse it back `@testruns.reverse.each`. Ok, if another code is need in this.

Comment: Incorporated the changes as per comments. Still... beside the point.

Answer (score 0):

Did this ever get solved?  I'm having the same problem.

```
class Field < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'FieldID'
  belongs_to :layout, foreign_key: :layoutid
end
class Layout < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'LayoutID'
  has_many :fields, foreign_key: :layoutid
end
```

When I code "puts Layout.joins(:fields).where('[dbo].[Layouts].layoutid = 3035').to_sql", I get the following which I guess is ok:

```
SELECT [dbo].[Layouts].*
FROM [dbo].[Layouts]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Fields] ON [dbo].[Fields].[layoutid] = [dbo].[Layouts].[layoutid]
WHERE ([dbo].[Layouts].layoutid = 3035)
```

I get the error when I try to do this.

```
l = Layout.find(3035)       # << Unknown bind columns.
l.fields.each {|f| puts f}
```

This is activerecord 4.1.6 and activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 4.1.0.

**FollowUp - My Problem Resolved**

```
class Layout < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'dbo.Layouts'
  self.primary_key = 'LayoutID'
  belongs_to :feed, foreign_key: 'FeedID'
  has_many :fields, foreign_key: 'LayoutID'
end
class Field < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'dbo.Fields'
  self.primary_key = 'FieldID'
  belongs_to :layout, foreign_key: 'LayoutID'
end
```

I had to make sure the cases were correct in the foreign key.  :layoutid and 'layoutid' did not work.  But 'LayoutID' does work, which matches the case in the sqlserver column definition.  That would be a nice note to have in the docs.